# "Normal" Text Visible on the Desktop - Ubuntu 16.04 fresh install

Tags: 16.04, display

[image: NORMAL]

I am unable to find the problem or what is causing this.

Comment: What is under that text `NORMAL` is important!

Comment: I think this string does not come from the desktop but from your physical display device. Do you have buttons to set display options like brightness, colors etc.? What happens when you pull a window over the 'NORMAL'? Does the text stay on top?

Comment: @mclux it stays there and I am running ubuntu on MSI Laptop with GTX 1070 and Gsync Display.

Answer (score 3):

if anyone wonders where that is coming from - it may be is the g-sync visual indicator - ran into the same problem and searched for ages :)

- open the Nvidia X Server Settings and go to `OpenGL Settings`
- disable the `G-SYNC Visual Indicator`

[image: open the Nvidia X Server Settings and go to OpenGL Settings]